# Навесить на поле класса анонимную функцию

Tags: c#

Как организовать поле в классе, на которое можно будет потом навесить анонимную функцию?
Мне нужно, чтобы в классе было поле, через которое я бы мог вызвать функцию, которая там определена

Есть класс **Process**, в нём есть поле **Name** и **Duration**. Есть класс **ProcessQueue**, в котором есть поле **Items** и **ItemIndex**. Так вот, я имитирую какие-либо процессы, указываю их название и продолжительность. Затем засовываю **Process** с заданными полями в очередь в поле **ProcessQueue.Items**. По окончанию процесса, должна сработать заданная пользователем функция. Я хочу засунуть эту функцию, скажем, в поле **Process.Callback**.

Как засунуть туда функцию и как её потом вызвать?

Comment: Создайте поле/свойство типа `Action<>`

Comment: Ну или любой свой делегат определите и заведите поле делегатного типа

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы записать в поле класса функцию, всё равно анонимную или нет, вы должны создать поле [*делегатного* типа](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/delegate). Для этого есть два основных пути: определение собственного делегата, или использование готового, имеющегося в системе. Предпочтительным методом является использование готового делегата.

Например, если ваш callback должен принимать один аргумент типа `int` и не возвращать никакого значения, вам подойдёт тип `Action<int>`:

```
Action<int> callback;
```

Присваивание выглядит просто:

```
callback = n => Console.WriteLine($"работа окончена, результат: {n}");
```

Вызов тоже очевиден:

```
callback(5);
```

Comment: а почему предпочтительно готовый?

Comment: @Grundy: Чтобы не плодить сущности сверх необходимого. Ну и плюс всякие библиотечные функции работают со стандартными делегатами, а не с кастомными. (Оно и понятно, откуда им знать о кастомных типах?)